# How to open a url in Iframe in accumatica

Tags: acumatica

how to open any url inside acumatica page like iframe.
example i want to open any url which is dynamic and value of url comes from database.
When i used
Throw new pxdirecttourlexception it is not working properly

public class SimpleRecordsMaint : PXGraph {

```
    public PXSetup<SimpleSetup> Records;

    public SimpleRecordsMaint() {

        if(Records.Current != null) {

            throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(Records.Current.Url, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.Same, "Redirect:" + Records.Current.Url);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to replace a specific frame of the website you can use HTML `target` attribute. For example, choosing main will replace Acumatica main frame:

```
throw new Exception("Redirect:https://www.acumatica.com$target=main");
```

[image]

Comment: This work only with https. My target is to open http Also

Comment: what do you mean by works only for https?

Comment: what lead you to believe it doesn't work?

Comment: maybe you can share URL if it isn't private data

Comment: https://www.acumatica.com
this will work Inside Acumatica

But if i Create a website in IIS and Opens it on other machines Browser it will work.
But if i open inside acumatica it not open
eg :-  
http://localhost:9998/Login/Login

Comment: Try to ping website in command line on "ping localhost:9998". If redirection target is localhost then it can be seen only locally. You could expose network IP of localhost to VPN if it applies at best. Also check iFrame with other tools like website https://iframetester.com/ to see if you can host target url.